# Bash function to check for unset and blank variables

Tags: bash

I'm writing a bash function to check for blank or unset variables.

```
function exit_if_var_does_not_exist {
    TMP_NAME=$1
    TMP_VALUE=`echo $TMP_NAME`
    if [ -z ${TMP_VALUE+x} ]; then
        echo "Variable [${TMP_NAME}] is unset. Exiting."
        exit 1
    else
        if [ ${TMP_VALUE} = "" ]; then
            echo "Variable [${TMP_NAME}] is set to ''. Exiting."
            exit 1
        fi
    fi
    echo "Variable [${TMP_NAME}] is set to ${TMP_VALUE}"
}

VAR=Test
exit_if_var_does_not_exist VAR
BLANK=
exit_if_var_does_not_exist BLANK
```

This does not give me the expected output in TMP_VALUE. Can someone please help me with what I'm missing here?

```
-bash-3.2$ ./x.sh
Variable [VAR] is set to VAR
Variable [BLANK] is set to BLANK
```

Comment: inside `[...]` you must quote the variables unlike `[[..]]`. You should also quote `"1"`.. Hold on, that will cause it's own problems. Interesting, let me test.

Comment: `TMP_VALUE` can't be unset because you set it to something. You may set it to the empty string but that's still "set" as opposed to "unset". Are you expecting `TMP_VALUE` to have the value of the variable whose *name* is in `$1`? Because that's not what you are doing here. For that you need indirect expansion `${!TMP_NAME}`.

Comment: Setting "TMP_VALUE=${!TMP_NAME}" did the trick. Thank you Etan and David

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with the empty test block is that at no point in this snippet do you ever actually get the value of the originally named variable.

When you use `TMP_NAME=$1` you assign the *name* of the input variable to `TMP_NAME` and then

```
TMP_VALUE=`echo $TMP_NAME`
```

just assigns that name to `TMP_VALUE`. Effectively you just ran `TMP_VALUE=$1`.

So you aren't testing for whether the originally named variable has contents anywhere here.

To do that you need to use [indirect expansion](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/006#Evaluating_indirect.2Freference_variables).

Namely `TMP_VALUE=${!TMP_NAME}` or `TMP_VALUE=${!1}`.

Side comment your "unset" test block at the top can *never* trigger.

`TMP_VALUE` can *never* be unset because you assign to it. Even `TMP_VALUE=` marks the variable as "set". So that bit is useless. Though, and thank David C. Rankin for trying long enough to make me think of this, you *can* use an indirect expansion trick to make this work.

`[ -z "${!TMP_NAME+x}" ]` will return true for any set variable named in `TMP_NAME` and false for an unset variable.

That all said if what you want to do is error if a variable is unset or blank the shell has you covered. Just use

```
: "${VAR:?Error VAR is unset or blank.}" || exit 1
```

Finally, as David C. Rankin points out inside `[` you need to quote expansions that might disappear when they change the meaning of tests (you see this in the `-z` test above) as well as here.

So `[ ${TMP_VALUE} = "" ]` needs to be `[ "${TMP_VALUE}" = "" ]` because is `TMP_VALUE` is empty the first version would become a syntax error because `[ = "" ]` isn't a valid invocation of `test`/`[`.

Comment: You need to quote variable in `: $var`, too. In that situation, `$var` is also subject to variable expansion and field splitting.

Comment: @cuonglm Yeah, realized that about two minutes after I posted this and walked away from the computer for the night. Good catch.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure this will work for all cases, but try:

```
#!/bin/bash

function exit_if_var_does_not_exist {
    local TMP_NAME=$1
    local TMP_VALUE="${!TMP_NAME}"
    [ -z "${!TMP_NAME}" ] && {
        echo "Variable [${TMP_NAME}] is unset. Exiting."
        return 1
    }
    [ "$TMP_VALUE" = "" ] && {
        echo "Variable [${TMP_NAME}] is set to ''. Exiting."
        return 1
    }
    echo "Variable [${TMP_NAME}] is set to ${TMP_VALUE}"
}

VAR=Test
exit_if_var_does_not_exist VAR
# BLANK=
exit_if_var_does_not_exist BLANK
```

**Output**

```
$ bash tstempty.sh
Variable [VAR] is set to Test
Variable [BLANK] is unset. Exiting.
```

---

**Improved Indirection Soup**

After a bit of discussion in the comments and a suggestion, I think I have a version that works more consistently. Again, I qualify this with I am not sure it will work in all situations, but for the testing it seems to:

```
#!/bin/bash

function exit_if_var_does_not_exist {
    local TMP_NAME=$1
    local TMP_VALUE="${!TMP_NAME}"
    if ! declare -p $1 >/dev/null 2>&1 ; then
        [ -z "${!TMP_NAME}" ] && {
            echo "Variable [${TMP_NAME}] is unset. Exiting."
            return 1
        }
    elif [ "$TMP_VALUE" = "" ]; then
        echo "Variable [${TMP_NAME}] is set to ''. Exiting."
        return 1
    fi
    echo "Variable [${TMP_NAME}] is set to ${TMP_VALUE}"    
}

VAR=Test
exit_if_var_does_not_exist VAR
# BLANK=
exit_if_var_does_not_exist BLANK
EMPTY=""
exit_if_var_does_not_exist EMPTY
```

**Output**

```
$ bash tstempty.sh
Variable [VAR] is set to Test
Variable [BLANK] is unset. Exiting.
Variable [EMPTY] is set to ''. Exiting.
```

Comment: `-z "${!var}"` and `"${!var}" = ""` are the same test.

Comment: Hmm..., scratching head and thinking.. Wouldn't `-z "${!var}"` test that the variable held in whatever name his held in var was unset, while with `"${!var}" = ""` the variable held in whatever name is held in var could be set but set to `empty-string`. Or have I lost something in the indirection... *Oh* .. lightbulb on - for `BLANK` the two tests are identical... due to `TMP_VALUE="${!TMP_NAME}"`

Comment: Right. The value of the indirection expansion is the value of the variable whose name is stored in `var`. The only way I can think of, offhand, to do an indirect unset test is to use `declare -p $var` (or similar) and catch the error.

Comment: Yes, I'm still scratching my head on a way to differentiate the two. I'll try a couple more ideas and update when I have something makes the second test useful.

Comment: Hah. I was just writing that you can't tell the difference between unset and empty from an expansion and then I thought "unless `${!var+x}` works" so I tried it... and it does. So `${!TMP_NAME+x}` will test whether the variable named in the argument is unset.

Comment: Well, I've thoroughly found myself in need of aspirin. Your suggestion of working with `declare -p` seems to work as well. Take a look at the improved jibberish. It seems to handle the three cases. I'm going to drill down on `${!TMP_NAME+x}` a little further and see what secrets it holds...

Answer (score 1):

Another way:

```
exit_if_var_does_not_exist() {
  if ! (set -u; : "${!1}") >/dev/null 2>&1; then
    printf 'Variable [%s] is unset. Exiting.\n' "$1"
    exit 1
  elif [ -z "${!1}" ]; then
    printf "Variable [%s] is set to ''. Exiting.\n" "$1"
    exit 1
  fi
  printf 'Variable [%s] is set to %s\n' "$1" "${!1}"
}
```

If you don't need to separate the two error messages:

```
exit_if_var_does_not_exist() {
  : "${!1:?$1 is unset or blank}"
  printf 'Variable [%s] is set to %s\n' "$1" "${!1}"
}
```